# Replacing only a limited number of times with a lot of .txt files at once

Tags: text

I have a lot of .txt files which contain text. In the text there are some symbols, let's say "@". They appear in random locations. I want to replace the first 2 of these symbols by another 2 symbols. So if I have "@@ ... @ ... @@" (with ... being text), I want to make it into this: xx ... @ ... @@ (if I want to replace @ by x).
I only want to replace the first 2 of the symbols, but I've only encountered  options that would either allow me to replace everything at once or nothing at all (at such a scale). Is there any program or feature that would allow me to do this with lots of files at once, in other words, I don't have to do it for each file manually?

Comment: What kind of system are we talking? Like, on the command line, or in a programming language? And can you expand on the options that you've found so far?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter how it's being done. I'm just looking for a way to do it. So far every editor I've found that can handle lots of files at once can only replace every character, so it can't only replace say 2 times and then stop.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in the `Vim` editor. Firstly, here is how to do it in one file. Say we have this file in the buffer.

```
junk
@@@@
@@@@
```

Here is the command to replace the first occurence of `@` in the file with `x`. To do two occurrences, we just execute it twice:

```
:0/@/s/@/x/
```

If we execute it once we get:

```
junk
x@@@
@@@@
```

and then if we execute it one more time we get:

```
junk
xx@@
@@@@
```

Anatomy:

```
  start search at 0 (before first line)
 | search for something
 || search for a line containing @
 |||  when you find @ perform a substitution command 
 ||| |  replace this
 ||| | |   with that (just once: the first occurrence in the line)
 ||| | |  |
 vvv v v  v
:0/@/s/@/x/
 ^
```

To run this command in place on a large number of files, we could automate that with a script, like:

```
 # find all the .txt files here and in all subdirectories,
 # and execute the command "ex <file> < script" on them

 $ find . -name '*.txt' -exec ex {} < script \;
```

We use the `ex` command which is an alternative name for `vi` to start it in ex mode, which accepts `ex` commands on standard input.

The `script` fille contains this:

```
0/@/s/@/x/
0/@/s/@/x/
x
```

I.e. do two of these replacements, and then `:x` to save and quit.

The colons that were used in vi are not necessary because the colon is a command in `vi`'s interactive command mode for entering an `ex` command.